# Trim braces from macro content

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I'm having macros with a content which may or may not have extra curly braces. I want to trim the extra braces but without expanding the rest of the content, if possible.

The following code shows the task:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\TrimBraces#1#2{\edef#1{\expandonce{#2}}}

\def\a{Test}
\TrimBraces\x\a
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test
% OK

\def\b{{Test}}
\TrimBraces\x\b
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test
% but is {Test}

\def\c{Test \textbf{Z}}
\TrimBraces\x\c
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
% OK

\def\d{{Test \textbf{Z}}}
\TrimBraces\x\d
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
% but is {Test \textbf{Z}}

\end{document}
```

Currently, `\TrimBraces` is nothing more like a stub which copies one argument to the other. I tried a lot of things with toks, but nothing worked as expected. I hope, somebody has a better idea. Maybe, it's even a known task.

**Update:**
My question is perfectly answered by the answers of David Carlisle, wipet and egreg, but  I can only accept one answer...

Comment: You should have left the tick to David, the basic idea is his.

Comment: @egreg OK, done :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm order is restored to the Universe

Comment: @David: You could borrow some bloke's TARDIS. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\TrimBraces#1#2{\expandafter\zzz\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\zz#2\zz}}

\def\zz#1\zz{#1}
\def\zzz#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}

\def\a{Test}
\TrimBraces\x\a
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test
% OK

\def\b{{Test}}
\TrimBraces\x\b
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test
% but is {Test}

\def\c{Test \textbf{Z}}
\TrimBraces\x\c
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
% OK

\def\d{{Test \textbf{Z}}}
\TrimBraces\x\d
\show\x
%-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
% but is {Test \textbf{Z}}

\end{document}}
```

Comment: this does work with `\def\a{{foo}bar}` :-)

Comment: Yes, it does. Works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 6):

My solution is only a little alternative to David's solution. The main point is the same: TeX removes outer braces from separated parameter if they exist:

```
 \def\aa#1\separator{...} \aa {text}\separator  -- #1 is text
                          \aa {text}b\separator -- #1 is {text}b
```

And my solution:

```
 \def\TrimBraces#1#2{\def\tmp{#1}\expandafter\trimbracesA#2\end}
 \def\trimbracesA#1\end{\expandafter\def\tmp{#1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take; it is assumed that `\@nil` doesn't appear in the expansion of the second argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\TrimBraces#1#2{\expandafter\TrimBraces@aux#2\@nil{#1}}
\def\TrimBraces@aux#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\makeatother

\def\a{Test}
\TrimBraces\x\a
\show\x %-- should be ->Test

\def\b{{Test}}
\TrimBraces\x\b
\show\x %-- should be ->Test

\def\c{Test \textbf{Z}}
\TrimBraces\x\c
\show\x %-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}

\def\d{{Test \textbf{Z}}}
\TrimBraces\x\d
\show\x %-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}

\def\e{{foo}bar}
\TrimBraces\x\e
\show\x %-- should be ->{foo}bar

\stop
```

Here's the log

```
> \x=macro:
->Test.
l.10 \show\x
             %-- should be ->Test
? 
> \x=macro:
->Test.
l.14 \show\x
             %-- should be ->Test
? 
> \x=macro:
->Test \textbf {Z}.
l.18 \show\x
             %-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
? 
> \x=macro:
->Test \textbf {Z}.
l.22 \show\x
             %-- should be ->Test \textbf{Z}
? 
> \x=macro:
->{foo}bar.
l.26 \show\x
             %-- should be ->{foo}bar
? 
 )
No pages of output.
```